# Find $_POST variable with same name as other variable

Tags: php, mysql, post, mysqli

I have a form being passed in `$_POST` where the names of each field correspond with data in a database

```
$_POST['test']; (has a value of 1)
$_POST['prod']; (has a value of 2)
```

Both `test` and `prod` are unique names in the database. Is there a way I can dynamically grab a `$_POST` variable? For example (some code that doesn't work)

```
$getServerIDs = $link->query("SELECT * FROM servers");
while($row = $getServerIDs->fetch_assoc()){
    $serverName = $row['name'];
    $newDisplayID = $_POST['$sName'];
    $updateDisplayID = "UPDATE servers SET displayID = $newDisplayID WHERE name = $servername";
    $runQuery = $link->query($updateDisplayID);
```

The `$_POST['$sName']` is the line of code being the problem. Whats the best way to fix this?

Comment: remove the quotes(') in $_POST[$sName], and also note that your code is vulnerable for sql injection :)

Comment: `$newDisplayID = $_POST[$sName];` is the right syntax

Comment: even without quotes `$sName` should be `$serverName`, no?

Comment: I tried this question 5 times but still can't get the logic. Silly me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with line `$newDisplayID = $_POST['$sName'];` you used single quote and when you put variable in single quote then it is not parsed by php use `$_POST[$sName];` or `$_POST["$sName"];`

**Edited**

[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/d73-41s)

Comment: @YourCommonSense any source of your thought? I've checked both and they are working. [Check fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/d73-41s)

Comment: Yes, they are working, in this particular case, but this is a wrong syntax.

Comment: If syntax was wrong wouldn't there be syntax error? I see none.

Comment: @YourCommonSense http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double says something diffrent. it is perfectly ok, so please remove the downvote (also from my post :S)

Comment: Sometimes a language allows us wrong syntax. It doesn't mean we should use it. Variables are addressed in PHP without any quotes. Using quotes is pointless and wrong.

Comment: The manual page you addressed to is on PHP strings. But the topic is PHP variables.

Comment: @YourCommonSense could you provide a link to manual where there is written that this syntax is wrong? In this particular case it's pointless but it's easy to make script where it'll be useful. Example `$b['test-b'] = 'asdfadf'; $a = 'test'; echo $b[$a."-b"]; echo $b["$a-b"]` both echos works.

Comment: [Variables in PHP are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) <-- here. There is no mention of quotes, braces or whatever else symbols you will have an idea to add. A dollar sign and a name. That's all.

Comment: Still I don't think the syntax is wrong. It's not best syntax in this case but I provided two pefectly correct examples. So I don't think that downvoted is justified. Morover, in my previous comment I've given example where "" in accessing variables may be useful. You wrote that this is working in this particular case, can you write the code where it won't work?

Comment: Guys, stop fighting. It's a style issue, not a language issue. But @YourCommonSense is mainly right -- it's very unusual to quote a variable when it's being used all by itself. Quotes are used when you want to interpolate the variable into a longer string, e.g. `"My name is $name"`.

Comment: You are confusing strings with variables, like most PHP users do. I can only hope someday you will learn the difference and the cost would be not too high.

Comment: @Barmar you are wrong too. it is not a "style" but the very syntax issue. And while it's rather quite usual for the PHP world, it's plainly wrong syntax.

Comment: It's not about strings it's about **SYNTAX** which is correct. PHP allows it as many other weird things. I understand very well the difference between variable and strings. In your way of thinking we should use statements like echo "hello $name"; because it's bad. All I do is just defending my opinion. I could get downvote if I wrote something wrong but I didn't. If you disagree with this syntax you can write to php developers. Btw. I don't use this syntax, this is only an option. As I wrote before can you write example of such code where there will be syntax error as you wrote above?

Comment: @YourCommonSense If `$variable` contains a scalar value (a string or number), `$variable` and `"$variable"` are equivalent.

Comment: a statement like `echo "hello $name";` is a string. You still confuse them with variables.

Comment: @Barmar really? `if ("$num" === 1) echo "equivalent";`

Comment: `if($a === "$a") echo 'ok 1';
if($b[$a] === $b["$a"]) echo 'ok 2';` both will display OK. 
Your case compares string with int so this can't be exact equal.(Types are different)

Comment: accessing an array via. a key should only be done via. integer or string values. accessing it via. a variable without checking the type can lead to problems. so quoting them for a string cast is perfectly valid.

$a = new Foo();

var_dump($a); // -> object (Foo)#1 (0){}
var_dump("$a"); // -> will invoke the tostring method

Comment: `if ("$num" === (string)1) echo "equivalent"` or `if ((int)"$num" === 1) echo "equivalent";` works? :> It's all about access via string or integer.

Comment: I am really sorry, but it is no use to continue without understanding the difference between a string and a variable. So, I quit. I am  only wondering why out of many useless (or useless and wrong) variants (like `$_POST[($sName)];` or `$_POST[("$sName")];` or `$_POST["".$sName.""];` - all used by PHP users everywhere) only `$_POST["$sName"];` were so favored to mention.

Comment: Because OP asked what wrong with single quotes and just to show him difference between single and double quotes. All this discusion started because you wrote that syntax is wrong. Maybe $a["$b"] isn't beauty but it isn't wrong, is it? Of course there can be other statements you can even write 1000 line function that will return string or int to access variable but it's still valid. That's the point.

Comment: First of all: nobody mentioned $_POST[($sName)] second of all these variants are NOT wrong but just bad-practice.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use quotes OR use double quotes.

Also be carefull you are using highly insecure code. Google sql injection

Comment: Why -1? +1 for mentioning SQL Injection.

Comment: @ChristianMark because Your Common Sense thinks that using double quotes is a bad syntax.. Check my answer and comments.

Comment: I don't get it, why here? I mean there is nothing wrong with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get all keys inside and array as `$_POST`.

```
$keys = array_keys( $_POST );
```

But be aware, that your user could add any key there in their submission. So you should in any case **filter and sanitize** this input!

Down the line you could then use this `$keys` array to do your output.